# How get position and derection the manipulator?

Tags: python

I need to get the position and directions of the manipulator for drawing a square in the 3d window.

[image]

Comment: it seems you mean the orthogonal direction from the selected face? that's called the face "normal" (face local z axis) but if you wish just to draw something like a rectangular "hole" in that face, you don't need to know its direction vector, though (and there would be no easy method to use it anyway to draw something along that direction): you can extrude the face edges scaling them toward inside.

Comment: I want to draw a square at the intersection of the axes http://take.ms/66Wve

Comment: see if this other questions (and answers) can help you http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7150/python-orient-light-to-polygon-face-normal-as-direction or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26116/script-access-to-tangent-and-bitangent-per-face-how

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, I have enough knowledge to find the position of the Median and orentation, but this is not what I'm looking for. I thought maybe in Blender api there is a function that will allow 2 - 3 lines of code to get the position and derection

Comment: maybe this one? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26053/get-the-selected-median-point-in-python

Comment: Oh, well, I'm glad you made some progress... I'm deleting my answer, since I completely misunderstood what you were asking. If you have now an answer, even partial, to you own question, you could consider adding an answer yourself, below: it will help everyone else. I can help with english, if needed :)

Comment: A little later I will answer with a code. Thanks for the extraneous activities you paid